# What is the difference between O(n^2) and O(N)[N*O(1)]?

Tags: asymptotics, hash

I was reading this [article](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/l-gperf/#toggle) on gperf.

In it they claim that the use of nested `if` statements for parsing command line input of $N$ options ends up making $O(N^2)$ comparisons.  (If I had just made one `if` for each option would it not be $O(N)$?)

Later on, they say that if instead the perfect hash function that gperf provides for the static keywords set is used the same program could make only $O(N)[N*O(1)]$ comparisons.

My first question is, could I plot these or get any intuitive sense for how different these actually are? (Not really sure, does this mean $N*O(1)$ is the same as $O(N)$)?

Second, this article really gives no basis for these time complexities they just give it as-is.  Is there any intuition for why these would make sense?

Comment: I think what he meant was it is O(N) due to N O(1) comparisions.

Comment: Reading the article, I'm as confused as you are. I don't see how it would take $O(N^2)$ if statement comparisons to determine which of $N$ options to perform. For your second question, yes, $N\ O(1)$ is indeed the same as $O(N)$.

Comment: OK so the bracket notation he is using $O(N)[N*O(1)]$ actually means to imply $N*O(1) = O(N)$?

Comment: That's the way I read it.

Comment: I think maybe they are saying if I put $N$ options as input, I would have to loop over each option (token), then make up to $N$ checks for each iteration to determine what each option was.  Whereas, with the other I would loop $N$ times but be calling a single $O(1)$ hash function each time.  So as the options increased the number of checks in the first approach would grow faster.